# Set HTML table cell title with php variable

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to set the title of each cell in a table from a php array. I can set the table content but found no way to parse the php variable to
`<td class="tg-0lax" title=<?php descr[0]; ?></td>`
etc.
Can someone help me with the correct way to do this?

Edit for code

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the code you already have, even if it fails.

Comment: please come up with some code

Comment: You're simply missing `echo` though you have the index `[0]`. Some tips: a variable can be echoed and a specific key that contains a variable (not another array) can be echoed. You can not echo an array itself. You can iterate through an array via a `foreach` loop: `foreach ($folders as $k1 => $v1) {echo '<p>'.$k1.' = '.$v1.'</p>';}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can print every variable in php using `echo` :

```
<td class="tg-0lax" title="<?php echo $your_variable ?>" ></td>
```